# Pandas: how to write a groupby plus an aggregation that can group by one or many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use this groupby plus aggregation operation in such a way that it can flexibly handle **one** or **more** groupby columns?

```
# some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'col2': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'col3': [999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999],
                  'time': ['2020-01-25 12:24:33', '2020-01-25 14:24:33', '2020-01-25 18:24:33',
                           '2020-01-25 09:24:33', '2020-01-25 10:24:33', '2020-01-25 11:24:33']})

# convert time
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# groupby with one col, works
df.groupby(['col1', df['time'].dt.floor('d')]).tail(1)

# how to use this structure while being flexibly able to group by one or more cols?
two_cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df.groupby([two_cols, df['time'].dt.floor('d')]).tail(1)
```

The expected output is the same for both operations:

```
    col1    col2    col3    time
    5   2   999 2020-01-25 14:24:33
    1   2   999 2020-01-25 18:24:33
    2   3   999 2020-01-25 11:24:33
```

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe, while explaining what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is looking for a list of labels for the `groupby()` function, and so we need to make sure that we give them a list. I believe this works.

```py
df.groupby(two_cols + [df['time'].dt.floor('d')]).tail(1)
```

You can see that our parameter in `groupby()` is our list `two_cols` + another list (in the `[]`) that contains just the `df['time']...` series. Thus, we are combining two lists into a new listobject, and that is what `groupby()` will run on.